# How does gmail use ajax?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-library

Looking at firebug, gmail sends GET requests to get something like:

```
while (true); &&&START&&&{"Success":true,"Body":{"Contacts":"[[,[,,\"83473f5sc6b17e0\",,[[,1,\"1\"]\n]\n[,,,[,,[,[,,,,,,,,,,,[[,1]\n
...
} &&&END&&&
```

- What are these arrays? Are these some sort of RPC?
- How are they consumed by the client code? More specifically, how would closure library use them?
- What is the advantage of this approach over plain json and REST?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like ordinary JSON, most likely a response to a RPC, but with the body encoded in some way (probably to reduce the size and therefore bandwidth usage). The `while (true);` bit is to avoid cross-site access to the data using a script tag pointing to the RPC endpoint - by crashing the script before it reaches the juicy private information it can prevent evil sites from using the data. Parsing instead would use `JSON.parse` or similar, after stripping off everything outside the start and end tags.

This kind of compressed encoding can be helpful if you are running a huge site like gmail, and have control over the client side. REST is however very useful for third-party developers, as it's easier to debug (and document!). The `while(true)` bits, however, are *essential* for any API that allows GET and carries sensitive data in the response.

Comment: How exactly the while(true) helps to avoid cross-site access to sensitive data?

Comment: The same question here: how does `while(true)` protect the sensitive data? The attacker can also parse the string.

Also, why is that `[,,,,,,]` is excessively used?

Comment: The attacker cannot parse the string, due to the same-origin policy. They can only include it, as executable code, in the page - the infinite loop stops the data from being executed (at which point cleverly replacing the array/map constructors can net the attacker the data). As for the `[,,,,,,]`, I don't know. It's some kind of internal gmail encoding. You'd need to reverse-engineer gmail's javascript to find out.

Comment: Those `[,,,,,]` seem to be serialized protocol buffers using closure library, [here](http://www.google.com/codesearch#epIciakqvFc/trunk/closure/goog/proto2/pbliteserializer_test.html&q=,,,%20package:http://closure-library%5C.googlecode%5C.com&type=cs&l=116) is a test unit example.